# Python loop timeout

Tags: python, timeout

I have a Python script that looks something like this:

```
for x in range(1000,40000):
    try:
       some_function(x)
       some_other_function(x)
    except Exception, e:
       print e
       pass
```

I know this is not good practice to handle errors like this but this is a script I'm only going to use once. Anyway, I noticed that the loop sometimes gets stuck on one particular id (x) and freezes for a few hours.

So my question is: How would I implement a timeout function in the loop so that if it takes more than 20 seconds then skip onto the next one?

Comment: Thread it, I think it's the best way for implementing a timeout.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11403275/748858

Comment: @mgilson - Windows 7. I looked at that thread but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is my first Python script so I'm an amateur (I'm a C++ programmer)

Comment: @DopeMonk You're right.  This is a different question. The other question wanted to exit the program, you just want to exit the loop.

Comment: I'd recommend figuring out why the function gets stuck and solving that problem at as low a level as practical, rather than band-aiding it with a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as a TimeoutException

```
except TimeoutException, e:
print e
pass
```

If you want it to go for only 20 seconds I'd suggest looking up creating signal handlers in python.  Heres an example and a link to the python documentation for it.
https://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20130511171949/http://pguides.net/python-tutorial/python-timeout-a-function/

Since you're on Windows, you might want to look at this older thread
[python: windows equivalent of SIGALRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm)

Comment: I don't think signals will work on Windows since there's no `SIGALRM`

Comment: I've already done `except Exception, e:` should that not handle all of the exceptions? The loop freezes for a few hours and no errors are printed it just starts again

Comment: Yes, I see if you had this running on Linux you could use `SIGALRM` to time you out in 20 seconds.  However, you have Windows, so you will have to use threading.  See my link to python: windows equivalent... it shows how to write a similar function to run on both OS.